# SQLAlchemy Engine hanging

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a multi-threaded program that shares one instance of `Engine` among all threads. It uses SQLAlchemy to access MySQL as well as Redshift. I have a `DbProvider` class that is used to obtain `Engine` instances: (It is subclassed for MySQL and Redshift)

```
def get_db_engine(self) -> Engine:
    if not self._engine:
        self._engine = create_engine(self._get_connection(), pool_size=_POOL_SIZE, max_overflow=_MAX_OVERFLOW,
                                     connect_args={'sslmode': 'verify-ca'})
        # verify-ca to avoid certificate domain mismatch error when CNAME forwarding to AWS endpoint

    return self._engine
```

The program hangs randomly and I haven't been able to find a way to reproduce this behaviour. However, after much effort, I've found two places where it hangs (which one happens depends on an input parameter):

```
url = db_provider.get_db_engine().url
```

or

```
db_provider.get_db_engine().execute(script)
```

where `db_provider` is an instance of `DbProvider` and `script` is a string.

My understanding is that `Engine` is thread-safe. I am going to try having a separate `Engine` for each instance, but this happens so randomly and scarcely that I can't rest until I know what the real problem is. Besides, separate engines also means separate connection pools which is likely to have a performance penalty.

Update: It seems that the program hangs at `create_engine`. Additionally, I sometimes get this error in logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 90, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1617, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1607, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3376, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3698, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3359, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 2670, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(abcd...) (at char 19), (line:1, col:20)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2998, in __init__
    super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 94, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "''"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/redshift_copier/vertical_copier.py", line 65, in _run_table_copier
    self._table_copier.copy(table)
  File "/app/redshift_copier/table_copier.py", line 62, in copy
    self._s3_to_redshift(table)
  File "/app/redshift_copier/table_copier.py", line 147, in _s3_to_redshift
    copier = S3RedshiftCopier(self._redshift_db_provider, s3_resource, self._redshift_copy_role)
  File "/app/redshift_copier/s3_redshift_copier.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._logger = Logger(obj=self, extra={log.FIELD_DATABASE: db_provider.get_db_engine().url})
  File "/app/redshift_copier/db_provider.py", line 96, in get_db_engine
    connect_args={'sslmode': 'verify-ca'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 56, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 139, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 214, in load
    return impl.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2405, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2411, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_redshift/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    __version__ = get_distribution('sqlalchemy-redshift').version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 562, in get_distribution
    dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3044, in parse
    req, = parse_requirements(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2991, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3000, in __init__
    raise RequirementParseError(str(e))
pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Invalid requirement, parse error at "''"
```

Comment: Engine might be, but connections aren't. `get_db_engine` looks like it might have a race condition of its own too, namely it might create more than 1 engine, which may or may not be a problem in the end.

Comment: I'm aware that connections are not thread-safe. I'm not sharing connections though, as far as I can understand. 
How could it create more than one engine? The `if` is checking for that?

Comment: It'd depend on how and where you're calling `get_db_engine`, but think about it: what if thread 1 comes around, evaluates the if condition and yields. Thread 2 comes around, evaluates the if condition and possibly yields etc.

Comment: You're right. I can't see how that would lead to hanging though. Still, the unlikeliness of this scenario is consistent with how rarely the problem occurs. I've updated the code to use `threading.local` to create an engine per thread. Waiting to see what happens

Comment: I agree that it should not lead to hanging. Just thought I'd point it out. In the end the result would be that sometimes some pieces of code would be using a separate engine, which should not cause your issues. From what you've presented it is really hard to see what's wrong. If at all possible, try and reduce your code until there's nothing extra left, but it still hangs, and then provide that here as a [mcve]. Also, when it hangs, do you see anything abnormal in the logs (your app, your DB) or anywhere?

Comment: Nothing abnormal. I used the logs to find where it was hanging since it's not easy to attach a debugger to a running Python program.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Please see the updated question

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost on that one. The error looks like either some package has corrupt info, or your setuptools is having a bad day.

Comment: Except if that were really the case it'd fail every time and would be easily reproducible :/